# Can I import Jira tickets into redmine

Tags: jira, redmine

How can I import "tickets" from JIRA to REDMINE. from a particular project on JIRA to a particular project in REDMINE

Comment: @mhsmith - Could i know the changes that you have made, to get this script working. I cannot import issues, comments and attachemnts. It is giving an error related to null values in priority ID. ( which it isn't in the database)

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Please avoid posting your own question as an answer. Best to post it as a new question instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like a Zapier service.

[Send new JIRA issues to Redmine](https://zapier.com/zapbook/zaps/4133/send-new-jira-issues-to-redmine)

Keep your issue tracking updated with this JIRA-Redmine integration. After you activate this Zap, every time a new JIRA issue is created, a matching issue will also be added to Redmine, providing effortless upkeep for your lists.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This worked for us: http://www.taskadapter.com/

The UI is a bit rough, but at least it can map the fields properly.

Edit: To expand on the answer, it's a utility that moves tasks between issue trackers. I think it works with MS Project as well, although we only used it for JIRA<>Redmine.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on PMSE. Can you please flesh out your answer soo it would stand alone even should your link stop working?

Answer (score 0):

In  Jira you can export to CSV: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/84144/how-to-export-issues-as-a-csv-file

There is a PHP based CVS importer for Redmine: https://github.com/juanmf/RedmineIssueImporter

The process doesnt look very straigthforward, but I guess it should be possible.

Also see this issue, which has some older other options for importing from a CSV: https://www.redmine.org/issues/7884

Comment: Redmine now has a native CSV importer shipped with Redmine itself.

Answer (score 0):

This script mostly works: https://github.com/Kulgar/jira2redmine

Though I had to edit it slightly to account for changes in the Jira XML format.