# How can I import JIRA issues into Redmine?

Tags: jira, redmine

I need to import JIRA issues into Redmine without Redmine then updating JIRA. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I've removed the request for software recommendations (software recommendations are out of scope).

Answer (score 2):

This is an older (8 years+) script made for JIRA to do an XML dump of information for import. A quick Google search and some reading got me there, I can't tell you if it will work or not but that seems to be your best bet: http://www.redmine.org/issues/1385

This question was also covered in another PM.se topic: [Can I import Jira tickets into redmine](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/17752/can-i-import-jira-tickets-into-redmine)

It links to another Zapier "Zap" (plugin), which I have used for other products, but again, not JIRA nor REDMINE: https://zapier.com/zapbook/zaps/4133/send-new-jira-issues-to-redmine/